# Concise Singleton impl that supports reentrancy

Tags: c#, singleton

I would like to find a concise C# implementation of the Singleton pattern, and I am wondering if it should support the following scenario.  What if my singleton's private constructor, as part of initializing the instance, calls a constructor that itself tries to access the singleton currently being initialized?  This is what I meant by [reentrancy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reentrancy_%28computing%29) in this question's title.  Some would say that a constructor shouldn't do anything complex enough that could lead to this occurring.  But what if, due to some future code change within the invoked constructors, it does happen?

I looked through the various answers to [this question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/79/).  I am impressed by the brevity of using `Lazy<T>`.  In the use case I am looking it, it throws an exception which is *much* better than constructing two instances of the singleton.  But alas, in throwing the exception it crashes the app which means it does not support the target scenario.

```
class Apple
{
    static readonly Lazy<Apple> instance = new Lazy<Apple>( () => new Apple(), true );
    public static Apple Instance { get { return instance.Value; } }

    private Apple()
    {
        // Call other methods which might access Instance...
        var testGet = Instance;
    }
}
```

So I have the idea to instead do the following.

```
class Banana
{
    static Banana instance;
    public static Banana Instance { get { return instance ?? new Banana(); } }

    private Banana()
    {
        instance = this;
        // Then call other methods which might access Instance...
        var testGet = Instance;
    }
}
```

It supports the target scenario, but is anything wrong with it?  Is there a better solution?

Please note the following before posting an answer.  Like many people, I still consider Singleton as a pattern.  Many DI enthusiasts like calling it an anti-pattern.  In the context of a project that relies on DI/IoC, this is a reasonable assertion.  Outside of that context, however, Singleton is still a valid design pattern.  I do not use DI and am not interested in discussing its merit points here.  Please do not post an answer below if it will refer to Singleton as an "anti-pattern", or if it will offer "dependency injection" as the solution.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this class need to support access from multiple threads?  If so, your solution doesn't handle it.

Comment: It seems to me that you're bent on enabling one anti-pattern (using an object before it's fully constructed) within another anti-pattern (the singleton pattern, which has problems beyond just DI). Enabling this *just in case* you end up with a horrible requirement (which should probably trigger a redesign anyway) doesn't seem like a good idea.

Comment: @JonSkeet The "method" called from within the private constructor is actually another constructor.  Calling it is just a part of initializing the instance.  This is a fairly normal practice and not an "anti pattern" as far as I know.

Comment: @HappyNomad: So why does that other constructor need the instance? And what guarantee will you have that it doesn't later start using some part of the state of the singleton that hasn't been initialized yet? Debugging type initializers which refer to each is really painful. Been there, done that, trying to avoid it wherever possible... Calling one constructor within another isn't an anti-pattern: using an instance before it's finished initializing generally is, and should be avoided where possible. (It's not always feasible, but it's worth putting some effort in.)

Comment: No, it's at least a double anti-pattern. Singletons with mutable state are usually bad, and handing out unfinished objects is bad as well. It's certainly not "normal practice". Circular dependencies are highly problematic, I'd throw an exception on re-entrance rather than access those incomplete objects. Circular dependencies of static constructors/field initializers are one of the worst kinds of circular dependency. Implicit locking by the runtime, potential dead-locks, undefined order of execution,...

Comment: @JonSkeet Point well taken.  Perhaps the `Lazy<T>` approach is best after all.

Comment: @CodesInChaos I have to disagree when you say that a mutable singleton is an "anti pattern" or "bad". If you insist, then please link to some proof. As for "handing out unfinished objects", yes that would be "bad" but I do not suggest doing so. Apart from those semantics, however, you suggestion is helpful.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although Singleton may not be considered an anti-pattern, accessing members of an instance before that instance is fully constructed *is* an anti-pattern.  You can't guarantee that code external to the class being initialized doesn't try using some uninitialized state.  So the scenario in question should *not* be supported.  If code that attempts to access the singleton is later added to the constructors invoked by the singleton's constructor, then that should trigger a redesign.

Using `Lazy<T>` as `Apple` demonstrates is the better approach since it throws an exception on re-entrance rather than accessing an incomplete instance.  `Lazy<T>` additionally supports access from multiple threads, if needed.