# Hand off instance before constructor returns

Tags: c#, constructor, anti-patterns

I have the habit of breaking the rules if it makes my code more concise or my API more convenient to use, and if I can thoughtfully get away with doing so in the specific circumstances.  I'd like to know if I can get away with the following such infringement.

The following illustration includes a single `Child` and single `Parent` class.  In fact, I am describing a common situation throughout my app.  My decision regarding this problem will affect numerous classes, which is why I'm asking this question.

```
public sealed class Child : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private Child()
    {
        //initialize basic state
    }

    public Child( Parent parent )
        : this() //invoke parameterless contructor to initialize basic state
    {
        this.Parent = parent; //the last thing before the public ctor exits
    }

    public Parent Parent
    {
        get { return parent; }
        set
        {
            if ( value != parent ) {
                parent = value;
                // initialize state that depends on the presence of a Parent instance
                parent.Children.Add( this ); //hand off to parent class
                OnPropertyChanged( "Parent" );
            }
        }
    }

    // INotifyPropertyChanged impl...
}
```

Notice in the `Parent` property's setter that I hand off the instance to the `Parent` class.  Also notice that I am invoking that setter from the public constructor.

On an [earlier question I asked](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18855036), it came up that handing off an instance that's not fully initialized is an anti-pattern.  It may be argued that that's what's happening here.  But I would say that it's not the case since basic state is initialized in the parameterless constructor which is called before the one accepting the `Parent` parameter.

I thought of a problem scenario arising if a `Child` subclass's constructor calls the base constructor with the `Parent` parameter.  If the derived constructor initializes basic state of its own then it won't be ready in time for the hand off.  But I figure I can solve that problem with the `sealed` keyword, if it fits the class's semantics as it does in my `Child` class's cases.

So am I good to go with breaking the referenced anti-pattern in these specific circumstances?  Or is there some consideration that I missed?

Comment: Why do you add the child to the parent on setting the parent in the property? There doesn't appear to be the corresponding code for removing children from parents they are no longer associated with. I might be inclined to move that into a more defined method as opposed to in a property setter, but other than that I can't see any missed considerations.

Comment: Isn't is possible to create an Add method to the Parent class which adds a Child to itself?

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth I actually have [an API that handles all that](http://www.qnomad.com/wpf/corehelpers/) (see "Bidirectional Associations").

Comment: You said `But I would say that it's not the case since basic state is initialized in the parameterless constructor which is called before the one accepting the Parent parameter.` When someone invokes the parameterful constructor, the parameterless constructor won't be called unless you invoke it / delegate to it explicitly from the parameterful constructor.

Comment: @ChrisW I just tested it.  Good call!  I was thinking about how the base parameterless constructor is implicitly called.  It's not the same case for `this()` though.  Thanks.

Comment: I'm surprised that in your OP to invoke `OnPropertyChanged` so early, i.e. before the property is completely set. I would have invoked that as the last line of the set-property implementation.

Comment: @ChrisW - Yup, agreed.  It would be better to put it at the end.

Comment: Your `Parent` property has a public setter, but there is no value you can set that results in the desired behavior. You'll get one of 1) an exception, 2) the node existing in the `Children` list of two different parents, or 3) the node existing twice in the `Children` list of its parent.

Comment: @280Z28 - Please see the link I posted farther up in these comments.  That will show you how I actually do it.

Comment: @280Z28 I imagine it's just sample code. The set-property implementation should start with something like, `if (parent == value) return; if (parent != null) parent.Children.Remove(this);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So am I good to go with breaking the referenced anti-pattern in these specific circumstances?

I think you're good.

I would do (have done) it myself: especially if a Child must always have a Parent, so that assigning it to the Parent is logically part of constructing the Child.

> Or is there some consideration that I missed?

One difference is that if the set property throws an exception, then the object is not constructed. That makes a difference if the child is disposable.

```
using (Child child = new Child())
{
   Child.Parent = null; // throws an exception
   ... etc ...
} // child.Dispose is invoked
```

versus

```
using (Child child = new Child(null)) // throws an exception
{
   ... etc ...
} // child.Dispose is not invoked
```

Answer (score 3):

You are correct, [leaking `this` during the constructor](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/09/02/don-t-let-this-get-away.aspx) is definitely something that you should avoid if possible.

In this case its **probably** fine (because you have marked the class as `sealed`), but why do something which looks like an anti-pattern when you can do it a better way instead?

The other nit-pick I have with your code is that the caller might not expect the act of creating a child to have added that child to the parents children, so in this case I'd probably change the pattern that you are using so that the callers code looks like this

```
var child = new Child();
parent.Children.Add(child);
```

And have the `Children` property set the `Parent` on the child when added.

Alternatively, if you **really** wanted to keep the above logic flow then I'd probably do something like this instead.

```
public sealed class Child : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private Child() { }

    public static Child CreateAndAddChild(Parent parent)
    {
        var child = new Child();
        child.Parent = parent;
    }

    public Parent Parent
    {
        get { return parent; }
        set
        {
            parent = value;
            parent.Children.Add( this);
            OnPropertyChanged( "Parent" );
        }
    }
}
```

Both of these solutions completely avoid leaking `this` in the constructor.

Comment: +1 for moving OnPropertyChanged to the end of the set-property implementation.

Comment: The "How much of a problem is this really?" section of http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/09/02/don-t-let-this-get-away.aspx suggests that the pattern is frequently used in practice.

Comment: @Justin - Thanks for the feedback.  But how, specifically, is your second alternative better than the code in my question (other than having moved `OnPropertyChanged`)?  I thought before of doing it this way, but a ctor is a method, too.  So long as the "dangerous" code comes last in the public ctor, I don't see how `CreateAndAddChild` is any better.

Comment: @HappyNomad As long as your class is sealed I'm not sure that its *technically* any better, however its now clear to anyone looking at your code that it conforms to the "don't leak partially constructed".

Comment: You also need to consider what might happen in the future - at the moment your class is sealed, however suppose in the future someone wants to extend your class and is in a hurry / doesn't realise the significance of why the class is `sealed` and so just removes the `sealed` keyword.  In reality this really isn't a big deal, but if you are interested in doing things the "right way" (and the presence of this question indicates that you are), then I'd argue that this method is *marginally* better :)

Comment: (1) It's a good rule of thumb - don't get me wrong.  But my purpose here is to thoroughly think through a possible exception to the rule. (2) If the class were not sealed then `CreateAndAddChild` is definitely not an option.  Which type would it instantiate - the base or the derived? (3) I only apply `sealed` to classes that I have semantic reason to assume won't be extended.  Also I can document `sealed`'s significance right there in the class's `Remarks` section.  Although I know it happens in many organizations, I'm not going to let anyone edit my code "in a hurry".

Answer (score 0):

This will confuse the consumer of your library.

Comment: And what if there is only one consumer, this class is documented and this method is not accessed from outside the library?

Comment: Knock yourself out then.